# Exclude URI from Jekyll Escaping

Tags: html, iframe, jekyll, liquid

In a webpage build with jekyll: How can I exclude a specific html-codeblock from escaping?

I want to embbed an iframe, but jekyll changes part of the url at built time.

I've tried to

- disable markdown rendering using `markdown="0"` in the exact same block I wanted to stay the same.
- put some content between the `<iframe>`-tags.

Both didn't change anything.

source code:

```
<iframe src="https://example.org/?q=run&do=true" width="100%" height="900px"></iframe>
```

output:

```
<iframe src="https://example.org/?q=run&amp;do=true" width="100%" height="900px"></iframe>
```

Every time I use the `&` in an url, it becomes `&amp;` in the static output. I want it to also be `&` after the jekyll build.

**Edit**:
This could also be a problem with kramdown parsing

Comment: Are you trying to display the iframe on the page, or to show the line of code on the page? If the latter: when I wrap the code in backticks, the code block renders correctly for me. Kramdown can also use `~~~` for displayed code blocks. See [here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#code-blocks) and [here](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#inline-code).

Comment: I'm trying to embbed the iframe into the page.

Comment: Make sure the iframe tag is not indented, or kramdown will think it's a literal code block.